# Can't create Relationship with the same node in Spring boot and neo4j

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j

i'm using spring boot wiyh neo4j and i can't create relationship with the same node (reflexive relationship)
This is my code:
Model:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Level {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Index(unique=true)
    private String name;

    private int nbr_transactions;

    private int coast;

    private double limit;

    private int nbr_downline;

    @Relationship(type = "IS_FOLLOWED_BY", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Level NextLevel;

...
}
```

And when i want to create two nodes i have errors

```
        Level l1 = new Level();
        l1.setName("Starter");
        l1.setNbr_downline(1);
        l1.setLimit(500);
        l1.setNbr_transactions(200);
        l1.setCoast(500);
        l1.setNextLevel(l1);
        service_level.addLevel(l1);
        Level l2 = new Level();
        l2.setName("Leader");
        l2.setNbr_downline(1);
        l2.setLimit(500);
        l2.setNbr_transactions(200);
        l2.setCoast(500);
        l2.setNextLevel(l1);
        service_level.addLevel(l2);
```

Errors

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

I don't know how to solve it! pls help!

Comment: Print the full stack trace of the NPE, or use your debugger, to determine which line of code is throwing the exception

Comment: I forgot @Autowired in service, it's working now thx